# SQL - Select only last order for every clients who had ordered before

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There are 2 tables, and I want to select only last order for each client that has ordered before...

**(cid,cname) Clients table**

1 , David

2 , Tom

3 , Alex

**(oid,cid,title,ordertime) Orders table**

1,1,"Tshirt",2013-10-1

2,3,"Ball",2013-10-1

3,3,"Food",2013-11-20

*Acording to tables Tom never ordered before. So he will not be listed. Alex ordered 2 times before and I want only show last order.

**Output must be like this :***

1,1,"Tshirt",2013-10-1, David

3,3,"Food",2013-11-20, Alex

I tried something like this code but Alex was listed 2 times. I dont understand how I can figure out.

```
select * 
from   Clients t2 
  left join Orders t1 
  on t1.cid=t2.cid 
where t1.ordertime<getutcdate() 
order by t1.ordertime desc**
```

Probably I must use Distinct or Group by but I dont understand how.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
    x.oid, 
    x.cid, 
    x.title, 
    x.ordertime,
    x.cname
From (
    Select
        o.oid, 
        o.cid, 
        o.title, 
        o.ordertime,
        c.cname,
        row_number() over (partition by o.cid order by o.ordertime desc) rn
    From
        Clients c
            inner join
        Orders o
            on c.cid = o.cid
    ) x
Where
    x.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.*, c.name
FROM orders o INNER JOIN clients c on o.cid = c.cid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(oid) as latestOrderid, cid FROM orders GROUP BY  cid) as latest
on latest.latestorderid= orders.oid
```

Comment: MAX(oid) isn't guaranteed to give you the latest order (although in practice it probably does)

Comment: agreed, I made an assumption there!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select o.*, c.cname
from clients c
join orders o on 
    c.cid = o.cid 
    and not exists (select * 
                    from orders o2 
                    where o2.cid = o.cid 
                        and o2.ordertime > o.ordertime)
```